# mule : Until successful doesn't accept the data weave transform

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a scenario where in I need to call the service until the http status of the webservice call is 200.
The subflow(SearchSubFlow) works fine when it is not in Until Successful but when it is inside Until Sucessful it falls over with the below error at Byte Array to String in SearchSubFlow.

org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler.

```
<flow name="CheckFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Internal_Listener" path="${CONNECTION_URI}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:proxy-service payload="envelope" doc:name="CXF" namespace="http://abc/RetrieveService" service="RetrieveService" soapVersion="1.2" wsdlLocation="${WSDL_RETRIEVE}"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <set-variable variableName="Ref" value="#[xpath3('//*:CheckRequest/*:Ref')]" doc:name="Get External Ref Number"/>
    <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="${RESEND_COUNTER}" millisBetweenRetries="${RESEND_INTERVAL}" doc:name="Retry to check policy status" >
        <flow-ref name="SearchSubFlow" doc:name="SearchSubFlow"/>
    </until-successful>

</flow>
<sub-flow name="SearchSubFlow">
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="PolicySearchWS Request">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

---
{   
    soapenv#Envelope: {
        soapenv#Header: {
            InsureJHeader:{
                role: "${HEADER_ROLE}"
            }
        },
        soapenv#Body: {
            arguments:{
                externalQuoteReference: flowVars.Ref
            }
        }
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Set Service Endpoint">
        <add-message-property key="serviceEndPoint" value="${APP_SYSTEM}/${SELECT_SERVICE_BASE_URL}/${.CREATE.ADDRESS}"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set SOAP Action">
        <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="${CREATE.SOAPACTION}"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" doc:name="Proxy"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Select_Request" path="#[serviceEndPoint]" method="POST" doc:name="Call Search WS">
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="200,500"/>
    </http:request>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="PolicySearchErrorMessage" value="#[xpath3('//*:Fault/*:ProcessingFault/*:message')]"/>
        <add-message-property key="httpStatus" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.status']"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
   </sub-flow>
```

Highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Try to debug your flow as NullPointerException is suspicious when Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler..

Comment: I am outputting the values used in transform in a logger before calling transform and it has the values, not sure why it throws NullPointerException

Comment: In global.xml I have added <spring:bean name="objectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore" id="Bean1" /> for the until successful. is there anything that needs to be added?

Answer (score 1):

Not referencing to the objectstore as below resolved the issue

```
<until-successful  maxRetries=5 doc:name="Retry to check status" >
        <flow-ref name="SearchSubFlow" doc:name="SearchSubFlow"/>
    </until-successful>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>` instead of `<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried and even tried now. Still get below error   org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler

Comment: Try to log the out put of the script whether is proper or not using <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

Comment: Even that failed   org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "message.payloadAs(java.lang.Class)" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler